# What is the name of my feedback procedure in control system that I am using?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control, systems-engineering, feedback-loop

I have created a self balancing robot. It uses PID control to control its pitch angle and gets the feedback from gyroscope and accelerometer. But I have not used any sensor to feedback the displacement to the controller. I have just approximated the voltage applying to the motor to the displacement through programming (let suppose 5v to the motor will make the motor to rotate for 1 rev/s and after integrating it , it will give the displacement covered). Through which I was able to maintain the robot at a single position. But now its time write the report and I do not know what to call this type of feedback of displacement.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call this [dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning), because you do not have any actual measurement of the position, but are just calculating it based on the estimated speed of the motor.

Comment: so, do you think i can write as estimated feedback of displacement?